# Independence of linear combinations of Brownian motions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $0<s\leq t\leq u\leq v$ and $W_x$ be a Brownian motion. Show that $aW_s+bW_t$ and $\frac{1}{v}W_v-\frac{1}{u}W_u$ are independent for $a,b$ satisfying $as+bt=0$.

The question seems easy but somehow I can't rearrange the terms to show the independence. I know that increments of Brownian motion are independent, so I tried to add, subtract, multiply, divide  but I didn't manage to make these increments appear. For example $aW_s+bW_t=aW_s+bW_t -(as+bt)W_s$ or $aW_s+bW_t=aW_s+bW_t -(as+bt)W_t$ don't lead me anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: the question doesn't seem well-formed. what is independent of what?

Comment: Are you sure that $as + bt =0$? Rewrite the sum as $(a+b) W_s + b(W_t - W_s)$. Then this is a sum of independent normals, so normal, with expectation 0 and variance $(a+b)s + b(t-s) = as + bt = 0.$ (?) it'd be a Dirac measure. (note also that $t^{-1} W_t$ is normal (0,1), which allows you to see what the difference is)

Comment: That is the statement of the problem. $aW_s+bW_t$ and $\frac{1}{v}W_v-\frac{1}{u}W_u$ are 2 random variables, and we need to prove they are independent. I think that variance should be $(a+b)^2s+b^2(t-s)$, am I wrong?

Comment: No it's as I wrote it (look at the elementary definition: if var(X) = $\sigma$, what is var(tX)? Don't forget the square root. In that case the only thing you need to show is that the difference is *not* the same Dirac measure at 0 - see my second remark above, and note var(x-y) = var(x) + var(y) in the iid case.

Comment: If $X$ has zero expectation than $var(tX)=E((tX)^2)=t^2E(X^2)=t^2var(X)$, right?

Answer (score -1):

Independence is equivalent to zero covariance when normals are jointly normal. So just compute the expectation of the product and see if it's zero.